# iphone X main screen doesn't rotate to landscape

Tags: iphone, display, screen

I want to rotate the main screen and all other iOS screens.

In Control Panel, when I set screen lock to off, neither control panel nor main screen rotate.

However, all apps rotate that have rotation capability, such as NOTES, MESSAGES, ETC.

iOS 14.4.2

Comment: iPads can rotate these screens, phones can’t. (On phone, can’t find citation)

Comment: @tetsujin can‘t check on iOS 14. but on 15 both Messages and Notes rotate on the iPhone.  Maybe it‘s a new feature not available in 14.

Comment: I have been using an iPhone X for a bit more than 3 years. Now it is on iOS 15 but its screen has never rotated while in the main or in settings although it has been while in many other apps.

Comment: @nohillside - I can't recall any instance of the main or settings screens rotating, right he way back to iOs 3 or so, ie as long as I've had iPhones. Messages & Notes always have - because that's the way I always turn them to get the larger keyboard, better for my fat fingers;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah, misread the question. You are right, control panel doesn't rotate.

Comment: @Tetsujin You are probably misremembering. The large screen iPhones from models 6 through 8, i.e. the Plus versions, could [rotate on the home screens](https://osxdaily.com/2015/02/20/rotate-iphone-home-screen/). Apple killed this feature, however, after the Face ID came out, i.e. starting with iPhone X.

Comment: @Alper - not really mis-remembering, just never had a large iPhone. [My 13 Pro Max doesn't count, I sent it back within 24 hours because of face ID, which I developed an immediate loathing for, & got an SE2 instead]